# Pasar file a traves de data AJAX - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, archivo, input

me encuentro en un dilema.
Estoy enviando los datos por separado a mi archivo php para procesarlos, el inconveniente que tengo es que no se como enviar el input file desde ajax, para que en php poder recibirlo como $_FILES['archivo']['name'] .
Por ahora desgloso el input file, pero solo envio el nombre y tipo como un string, necesito enviar toda la data para poder recibirlo como file completo.

```
if($('#archivo').val().length >= 1){
            var inputFileImage = $("#archivo")[0].files[0];
             fileName = inputFileImage.name;
             fileType = inputFileImage.type;
        }

        var data = {
            nombres: $('#nombres').val(),
            cedula: $('#cedula').val(),             
            nombres_com: $('#nombres_com').val(),
            cedula_ruc: $('#cedula_ruc').val(),
            direccion_inm: $('#direccion_inm').val(),
            ficha: $('#ficha').val(),
            codigo: $('#codigo').val(),         
            fecha: $('#fecha').val(),   
            imagen: fileName,   
            tipoimagen: fileType,
            adicional: $('#adicional').val(),

        };


        $.ajax({
            url: 'actions/registros.php',
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {

                console.log('codigo '+response.code);
                switch (response.code) {
                case 0:
                    //CreatePNG(data);                      
                    $('input[type=text]').val('');
                    $('input[type=mail]').val('');
                    $('input[type=tel]').val('');
                    $('input[type=date]').val('');     
                    $('input[type=file]').val('');   
                    $(".previsualizarEditar").removeAttr('src');        
                    $('#enviar').css('pointer-events', 'auto');

                    swal('Muchas Gracias!',response.mensaje,"success");
```

Answer (score 1):

Has tratado enviando todo el formulario

```
<form id="miForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<!-- lista de inputs -->
<input type="file" name="nombreArchivo">
</from>
```

Y enviarlo mediante jquery

```
$("#miForm").submit(function() {
   var formData = new FormData($("#miForm"));
   $.ajax({
        url: 'actions/registros.php',
        type: "post",
        data: formData ,
        success: function(response) {/*block code*/}
   }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, si lo consideré, pero es que aparte de los datos del formulario, envio otros datos, por ende no puedo solo enviar el form.

Comment: @EdisonCobos Todos los campos de tu formulario van a incluirse en `formData`, no solo el archivo. Al menos inténtalo.

Comment: estocen usa contentType: 'multipart/form-data'